# IWebBrowser2 and socks4/5 proxy

Tags: windows, webbrowser-control, socks, iwebbrowser2

It seems that web browser component (Windows 7, IE11) can't browse at all in case it's specified by a user in settings to use socks proxy.
Internet Explorer works, my application based on web browser component can't browse any site - I got network error. 
Sample application from MSDN acts the same way as my app.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOCKS4 works for me. Form your app, check if the correct proxy setting is there, with `UrlMkGetSessionOption`/`INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY`.

That said, most likely you're dealing with some firewall/antivirus software which is configured to allow SOCKS requests from a certain white list of approved apps (including `iexplore.exe`). Your app is not on the list.